# How to run two functions with different arguments run parallely in python with in a fastapi method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

I have two functions which take in different arguments as input, and I am looking for a way to run them parallely at once, both functions returns somethings and I want to get the results back as well,

```
def func1(arg1),
    return arg2

def func1(arg2):
    return args
```

I have tried using, `ray` but its taking a lot of time than executing sequentially,

```
import ray
ray.init()

@ray.remote
a = func1.remote([1,2,3])
b = func2.remote([4,5,6])
func1_results, func2_results = ray.get([a, b])
```

I know we can use multiprocessing, but how can I store the return results and is this the correct method? Also how can I pass arguments for each function separately?

I got this example from another answer,

```
from multiprocessing import Process


p1 = Process(target=method1) # create a process object p1
p1.start()                   # starts the process p1
p2 = Process(target=method2)
p2.start()
```

Note: Multiprocessing directly is not working inside fastapi method

Comment: Why do you need to run them parallely? What would be the use of that? There will probably be a way to not need them to run parallely - at least, I can't think of any case in which you need to.

Comment: @megargayu the above functions are examples only, my real function is much more complex and cpu and io bound,  I need to run them parallel for reducing code execution time

Answer (score 1):

You can use threads for simplicity but if you really must use Multiprocessing you can share results with Queues. Pass the queue through parameters or initialize it outside the scope.

Following your example...

```
from multiprocessing import Process,Queue
import os

def func1(arg1,queue):
    return queue.put(arg1)

def func2(arg2,queue):
    queue.put(arg2)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    queue = Queue()
    p1 = Process(target=func1, args=([1,2,3],queue))
    p2 = Process(target=func2, args=([4,5,6],queue))
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
    queue.put("Done")
    
    while True:
        msg = queue.get() 
        print(msg)
        if msg =="Done":
            break
```

Output:

```
[4, 5, 6]
[1, 2, 3]
Done
```

Comment: I read in multiple places that due to global interpreter lock of CPython, threading is unlikely to achieve true parallelism (GIL states that only one thread can execute at a time),  so multiprocessing should be ideal solution.

Comment: There are pros and cons, multiprocessing is faster but spawns slower. Also you have to take measures to share memory objects. I could put the example with Multiprocessing its really similar

Comment: Yeah, I need to run them parallel, if its not too much please can you provide an example using my use-case, two functions while each one takes different argument.

Comment: Can you use my two example functions so I can relate and better understand it? Also in which variable does the function returns get stored?

Comment: You get them in the queue object. with queue.get() you get the first element of the queue

Comment: Do I need to run the while loop?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228064/discussion-between-zamar-and-user-12).

Answer (score 1):

If you’re using an up-to-date Python version you can achieve what you want using asyncio, coroutines and tasks.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html

```py
import asyncio
import time

async def func1(arg1):
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    return "1 says " + str(arg1)

async def func2(arg1):
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    return "2 says " + str(arg1)

async def main():
    task1 = asyncio.create_task(func1('hello'))
    task2 = asyncio.create_task(func2('world'))

    print(f"started at {time.strftime('%X')}")

    print('should take 3 secs, not 5.')
    done = await asyncio.gather(task1, task2)
    print(done)

    print(f"finished at {time.strftime('%X')}")

asyncio.run(main())
```

Sample output. Note that if func1 and func2 were cpu-bound then asyncio would not be able to schedule them so fairly, as mentioned in another answer.

```
$ python3 user_12_gather.py
started at 19:29:24
should take 3 secs, not 5.
['1 says hello', '2 says world']
finished at 19:29:27
```

Comment: Isn't asyncio still runs functions one after the another? It's different from multiprocessing right?

Comment: There is different yes. You can get coroutines to run concurrently by using Tasks but it’s event loop cooperative multitasking rather than threading.

Comment: But I think coroutines still start process one at a time and execution will only happen if one task is completed right? What I need is both running parallely in background and getting the results, If you can please provide some example so I can understand it

Comment: i added an example to the answer showing two coroutines, one sleeping for 2 seconds and the other for 3 and they both complete in 3 seconds total because they are running in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

The real answer is that it depends almost entirely on what func1 and func2 will be doing. There are many parallelism options in Python 3 and each is designed for a different use case.

If each function is reading a data stream and doing some relatively quick operation on each item then asyncio will work really well for that use case, because each function will spend most of its time waiting for io completion and asyncio will be able to switch the execution context between them very well and easily.

However if the functions are cpu-bound (e.g. you're sending each one off to compute pi to 1000 digits) then iosync won't work well because it has no opportunity to switch between them. You can improve that by adding async.sleep(0) as a hint that this would be a good place to switch, but fundamentally only one will run at a time.

For the cpu-bound use case, you need more than one execution context to achieve parallelism. The simplest option is threads in a single process, but the global interpreter lock in Python limits the achievable performance with that solution, as you noted.

The other option is to fork each work stream into a separate process and let the kernel handle the concurrency. There are many ways to implement that, ranging from simple fork, to the subprocess module, to the multiprocessing module. Each has its own merits in a trade off between complexity and functionality, but fundamentally they all fork separate processes and let the kernel handle the parallelism.

Comment: Many applications are a mix of both io and cpu and then you have to consider the machine you're going to be running on. If it has a large number of cores then multi-process will work well because the kernel will be genuinely able to run them concurrently. If it has one or two cores like a small VM then asyncio may still perform better. Again there is no "one size fits all" solution.